# Media seek prediction in advance

Tags: media-player, mp4

I am trying to implement a light weight HTTP server for movie playback (using progressive download).
I was thinking to efficiently implement seek function when media player requests HTTP GET with media range.
I am under impression that next seek position can be predicted (by inspecting moov atom) before media player request with 'Range' request.

Is my understanding correct? If so, how to get seek position in advance?